# Execute search in API from Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to execute a search from the Action Bar.
The Activity that I call in the Intent, GetBookInfo.class, retrieves info about a book from the Google Books API.

My problem is that, when I start to write, it only allows me to write a  letter of the word, not the whole book's title, so the search never works. How can i fix this?

I have the following code in my "MainActivity".

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetBookInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;
        case R.id.exit:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Salir")
                    .setMessage("¿Estás seguro?").setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetBookInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This will allow you to type your full text and when you submit, will `Intent` to `GetBookInfo` `Activity`

`onQueryTextChange` is fired when any character is added/removed/modified inside `SearchView`, so currently as soon as you type first character, your intent was triggered

Hope it helps!